# Matplotlib Histogram with non numerical data

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Can not plot an Histogram in Matplotlib with non numerical data.

A = na, R, O, na, na, O, R ...

A is a dataframe that takes 3 different values: na, R, O

I try:

```
plt.hist(A, bins=3, color='#37777D')
```

Would expect something like this [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq4rr.jpg)

It works with numerical data, but with non numerical data I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-60369a6f9af4> in <module>
      1 A = dataset2.iloc[:, 2 - 1].head(30)
----> 2 plt.hist(A, bins=3, histtype='bar', color='#37777D')

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in hist(x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, normed, data, **kwargs)
   2657         align=align, orientation=orientation, rwidth=rwidth, log=log,
   2658         color=color, label=label, stacked=stacked, normed=normed,
-> 2659         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2660 
   2661 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(self, x, bins, range, density, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, normed, **kwargs)
   6563                     "color kwarg must have one color per data set. %d data "
   6564                     "sets and %d colors were provided" % (nx, len(color)))
-> 6565                 raise ValueError(error_message)
   6566 
   6567         # If bins are not specified either explicitly or via range,

ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per data set. 30 data sets and 1 colors were provided
```

Comment: What do you want to see if you plot non-numerical data?

Comment: A histogram with the distribution of the 3 different options: 1 bar with the amount of na´s, other bar with the amount of O´s and one last bar with the amount of R´s.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a bar chart instead of a histogram. Moreover, it is unclear what your values are. Considering they are strings (based on the plot), you need to first count their frequencies using for example `Counter` module. Then you can plot the frequencies and assign the names of the keys as the tick labels.

```
from collections import Counter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

A = ['na', 'R', 'O', 'na', 'na', 'R']

freqs = Counter(A)

xvals = range(len(freqs.values()))
plt.bar(xvals, freqs.values() , color='#37777D')
plt.xticks(xvals, freqs.keys())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not reproducible. But if we create a dataframe and run the following code

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(["na", "O", "A"], size=10))

plt.hist(df.values, histtype='bar', bins=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now this may not be the best choice anyways, because histograms are continuous by definition. So one may create a bar plot of the counts instead.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(["na", "O", "A"], size=10))

counts = df[0].value_counts()
plt.bar(counts.index, counts.values)

plt.show()
```

[image]